# provision_key is not coming in kong oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, kong

I tried to use `kong api` manager with **oauth2**. As per documentation i did api registration in `kong` and I added **oauth2** plugin to that service but `provision_key` is not came in my response. please help on this

```
http://10.20.0.151:8001/apis/myservice/plugins
**Request** : name=oauth2

**Response**: 
{
  "api_id": "df79169c-dcdb-4b3f-98ea-a19d79f5b5f3",
  "id": "657b319c-cfb8-44c5-86c9-e2847c6d98db",
  "created_at": 1473007130000,
  "enabled": true,
  "name": "oauth2",
  "config": {
    "hide_credentials": false,
    "mandatory_scope": false,
    "enable_password_grant": false,
    "token_expiration": 7200,
    "accept_http_if_already_terminated": false,
    "enable_implicit_grant": false,
    "enable_client_credentials": false,
    "enable_authorization_code": true
  }
}
```

Comment: It isn't 100% clear, is that a response from an HTTP GET against the plugin endpoint or the result of a POST to create the plugin

Comment: Post request. Not get

Comment: Same here - I submitted this as https://github.com/Mashape/kong/issues/1653

Comment: Did you also use Kong Dashboard, or did you `curl` it in?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your own provision_key in the OAuth2 plugin configuration

```
$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8001/apis/{API}/plugins/ -d "name=oauth2" \
    -d "config.scopes=email, phone, address" \
    -d "config.mandatory_scope=true" \
    -d "config.enable_authorization_code=true" \
    -d "config.provision_key=987654321ACB"
```